# Prediction with very less data

Tags: predictive-modeling

Here is a question I am struggling with

Training data:

```
start = "2013-01-01"
end = "2013-01-01"
temp = [24,
        34.38,
        34.36,
        34.74,
        35.26,
        35.23,
        35.29,
        35.64,
        36.02,
        36.1,
        36.98,
        37.01,
        36.75,
        36.01,
        35.66,
        34.72,
        33.9,
        32.62,
        31.51,
        30.73,
        29.5,
        26.94,
        25.47,
        23.84,
        22.55]
```

Explanation: Above is the training data of temperature of a room for a single day. Predict for next 2 days.

Visualization of above temperature series
[image]

There is a same question (with some more info) at this [link](https://github.com/reachsumit/digital-data-scientist-hiring-test-powered-by-hackerrank/tree/master/Question%203)

My Question:
How to solve this question ? What model should be used for such a question ?

My thoughts:

1. It looks like time series model. But to use any time series model training data should have trend and seasonality which does not seems to be there (as seen in the above visualization).
2. One can try linear/non-linear regression models by making on input feature(s) (eg. depicting hour of day starting with 0 to 23) but that would mean the model would predict same set of temperatures every day.
3. Decision tree with input feature(s) (eg. depicting hour of day starting with 0 to 23) but decision tree is to big model for such small dataset it may over fit.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: apply some regression, eg linear regression, although for very small time intervals the maximum entropy estimation is simply the projection of same value into the future

Comment: Imho the best prediction which can be done from this one-day data is to predict exactly the same temperature at exactly the same time, and you don't need any ML for that. I would be very surprised if any ML method not using any other data can beat this baseline.

Comment: @NikosM., can you explain in simpler words ?

If I fit a linear regression line, for both of the next 2 days the predicted temperature will be same although they might be different from the training data temperatures

Comment: As both I and Erwan have pointed out, simple projection into the future is the best prediction for this case

Comment: Definitely can gather more data or add more variables to predict for each hour.

Comment: Thanks @Adhira for the input but I think more data wasnt option given and adding more features to less data I believed that even simple models might start to overfit.

Comment: @NikosM. Ok, thanks for your inputs.

Comment: @HiteshSomani
With correlations you can identify which features are more important and then build the model based on only those few important features.